# Model is invalid on post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-5

We are trying to pass our ViewModel to our controller using the submit of the form. When the ViewModel arrives at our POST method, it's invalid and null.

**VraagViewModel:**

```
 public class VraagViewModel
{
    public List<Thema> Themas { get; set; }
    public List<Gevolg> Condities { get; set; }
    public Vraag Vraag { get; set; }
    public List<Gevolg> GekozenCondities { get; set; }
    public Thema Thema { get; set; }
    public Antwoord Antwoord { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UnitOfWorkManager uow = new UnitOfWorkManager();
        IThemaManager mgr = new ThemaManager(uow);
        ITestManager testmgr = new TestManager(uow);

        Models.VraagViewModel model = new Models.VraagViewModel
        {
            Themas = mgr.GetThemas().ToList(),
            Condities = testmgr.GetGevolgen().ToList(),
            GekozenCondities = new List<Gevolg>()
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Index(Models.VraagViewModel model)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(model.GekozenCondities.Count); //Nullpointer here!

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            Debug.WriteLine("ModelState not valid!");                 
    }
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@model  UI.Mvc.Areas.Admin.Models.VraagViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<h2>Vraagbeheer</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<p>@Html.DropDownList("Themas", new SelectList(Model.Themas))</p>
<p>@Html.TextArea("vraag", "Hier komt de vraagtekst")</p>


<p>@Html.ListBox("Condities1", new SelectList(Model.Condities), new { id = 
"condities1" })</p>
<p>@Html.ListBox("Condities2", new SelectList(Model.GekozenCondities), new { 
id = "condities2" })</p>

<p><button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-default">Conditie 
toevoegen</button></p>
<p><button type="button" id="remove" class="btn btn-default" 
onclick="verwijderConditie">Conditie verwijderen</button></p>


@Html.TextArea("antwoord1", "Voor- en nadelen\nAntwoord1")
@Html.TextArea("antwoord2", "Voor - en nadelen\nAntwoord2")
@Html.TextArea("antw1Kort", "Antwoord 1")
@Html.TextArea("antw2Kort", "Antwoord 2")
<input id="gevolgInvullen" type="submit" value="Gevolgen invullen" 
class="btn btn-default" />
}

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#add").bind("click", function (e) {
            $("#condities1 > option:selected").each(function () {
                $(this).remove().appendTo("#condities2");
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $("#remove").bind("click", function (e) {
            $("#condities2 > option:selected").each(function () {
                $(this).remove().appendTo("#condities1");
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        /*$("gevolgInvullen").bind("click", function () {
            Url.Action("Action", "Controller")
        })*/
    });
</script>
}
```

**Question**

We would like to know what causes the ViewModel being null when it arrives in the POST method in our controller.

**EDIT 1**

It seems that the model itself [is not null.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTR25.png)

Comment: Have you confirmed it is model that is null and not its GekozenCondities property?

Comment: you could post the exact error message you are getting

Comment: It seems that the model itself is not null. Everything inside the model is null except GekozenCondities and Themas (both with Count=0).

Comment: Your view is generating form controls that have no relationship at all to your model. And how would you expect `GekozenCondities` to contain anything when you never generate any form controls for it. I strongly recommend you buy yourself a good book and learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

You have no field called: GekozenCondities in your form, so of course it will be null...

In your form it is called Condities2

```
<p>@Html.ListBox("Condities2", new SelectList(Model.GekozenCondities), new { 
id = "condities2" })</p>
```

change that to;

```
<p>@Html.ListBox("GekozenCondities", new SelectList(Model.GekozenCondities), new { 
id = "condities2" })</p>
```

But I think this will not work anyway as it will post only 1 value (The **selected** value from the dropdown) but in your model it is a list...

Read up on the basics of forms?

Comment: It's a `ListBox` input so it _can_ pass multiple selected values.

Comment: Cool, in that case that should fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Your model is null after post because on view , Inside form , It does not contain any property of **VraagViewModel** class. You need to assign proper control's name.

e.g let suppose this is your class.

```
public class VraagViewModel
    {
        public Antwoord Antwoord { get; set; }
    }
    public class Antwoord
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Then on your view your control name would be **Antwoord.Name**
like thi

```
<input type="text" name="Antwoord.Name"/>
```

OR

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Antwoord.Name)
```

Then you can access it in your action using **model.Antwoord.Name**